# How did Tuco know where to pick up Jesse?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In episode "Seven thirty seven" (S02E01) of Breaking Bad, while talking to Skyler who is taking a bath, Walt gets a phone call from Jesse which he dismisses due to Skyler's company. He looks out through a window, sees Jesse's car and steps outside to meet him, only to be greeted by Tuco sitting in the back seat who turns his gun towards him and tells him to get in.

How did Tuco know where to pick up Jesse in the first place?

Although Jesse and Tuco seem to have some minor connection (e.g. through Skinny Pete), Jesse first meets Tuco in season 1 and they never get together anywhere near Jesse's place. In fact I don't think they even swap phone numbers which leads me to wondering how they scheduled their first meet-up at the scrapyard but that's just detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd probably make for a terrible criminal.

You really think a person like Tuco just randomly starts associating himself with two strangers, without doing any sort of background check or having them followed? At the very least, there's always a check-up to see if at least you are not dealing with undercover cops. During that check-up, somebody's address is probably the easiest to find.

Obviously not something Tuco himself does, he just gets one of his henchpeople to do it.

Comment: That's interesting, I would indeed make a bad criminal, how would a criminal go about police informant detection ?

Comment: @JamesWell: Tuco's methods are not explicitly established in Breaking Bad. Given his cartel connections, his ability to run these checks is well established, even if the exact method of doing so isn't.

Comment: We see a bit more into the Salamanca's cartell practices in Better Call Saul, including how Nacho goes about stalking the Kettleman's, which he learns about through Jimmy's newly hired idiot skateboarder con duo, making a mistake by following the wrong car and ending up at Tuco's mother's house! BCS shows a lot of interesting ways people can get information from screaming manipulation, dumb luck, to having access to information, such as Jimmy and Mike having access to either Police Department or Criminal Justice system, as Mike is a former cop and Jimmy a former public defender and con artist.

Comment: In other words these characters have a lot of connections.

Comment: Maybe like a police informant secretly divulging investigation related information to his fellow gang members ?